# how to display jbutton on the splashscreen

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, splash-screen

How to add button to splash screen

Hi i have to create [java splashscreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) and during splash it will halt/pause and display ok button. I have made splash screen run every time i compile netbean.

```
public class Main
{
  static SplashScreen mySplash;    // instantiated by JVM we use it to
                                   // get graphics
 static Graphics2D splashGraphics;  // graphics context for overlay of the
                                   // splash image
 static Rectangle2D.Double splashTextArea;       // area where we draw the text

 static Rectangle2D.Double splashProgressArea;   // area where we draw the progress bar

 static Font font;                               // used to draw our text

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   splashInit();           // initialize splash overlay drawing parameters

}

 //create button here
 private static void splashInit()
{

  //do coding here for mannipulating splash screen
  //put ok button here

 }
}
```

How can we possibly put button to splashscreen? Usually I can only put `JButton` at `JFrame` or `JPanel`. Is it possible to put button on images like splash screen?

reference : [Splashscreen beginner netbean](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Splash_Screen_Beginner_Tutorial)

Comment: Consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for faster help.m In it's current state, your code doesn't say much, except that you may be using `Thread.sleep` unnecessarily.

Comment: oh ok i will review my code

Comment: Then it's not quite a splash screen. Why not simply display an undecorated JDialog and put your button on that?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels , I will look into it. Jdialog is still  new for me. ill try google for more info

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, well in my splash screeen i have progress bar and splash text display while splash screen running, i doubt jdialog have the ability to do as splash screen would. hmm

Comment: You're saying that a JDialog wouldn't have the ability to show a JProgressBar and text while a background process has been running? Then I've been programming wrong for all these years?! Seriously though, where did you get this idea of JDialogs limitations? No, it wouldn't be technically a splash screen, but it certainly could function like one, and then some, including holding your JButton.

Comment: thanks @Hovercraft Full Of Eels +1 for that, so JDialog can actually be used as splash screen. I will work on it. Can you kind enough to instruct me on how to make jdialog as splash screen? sorry if by any chance my question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Can you kind enough to instruct me on how to make jdialog as splash screen? "

In the example below, here are the things I do.

- Create a `JDialog` class and make sure it is `undecorated`

  ```
  public class SplashDialog extends JDialog {
      ....
      setUndecorated(true);
  ```
- Give it a background image

  ```
  JLabel background = new JLabel(createImage());
  background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  setContentPane(background);
  ```
- Add a `JPanel` with a `JButton` to the `background`. But set the `JPanel` not visible, also just to add some styling, give the `JPanel` a little transparency, so when you *do* set it visible, you can still see the `background` image

  ```
  final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
  panel.setVisible(false);
  panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 150));
  JButton okBut = new JButton("OK");
  panel.add(okBut);
  background.add(panel);
  ```
- Use a `javax.swing.Timer` to set the delay for the button to appear.

  ```
  Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          panel.setVisible(true);
      }
  });
  timer.setRepeats(false);
  timer.start();
  ```
- Make sure the frame isn't visible, but when the button is pressed, the frame becomes visible and the `JDialog` disposes

  ```
  okBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          dispose();
          parent.setVisible(true);
      }
  });
  ```

Now you have yourself a simple slash screen

Initial splash

[image]

Splash After 5 seconds

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SplashDialogDemo {

    public SplashDialogDemo() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 400);
            }
        };
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        SplashDialog splash = new SplashDialog(frame, true);
    }

    public class SplashDialog extends JDialog {

        public SplashDialog(final JFrame parent, boolean modal) {
            super(parent, modal);

            JLabel background = new JLabel(createImage());
            background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setContentPane(background);

            final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            panel.setVisible(false);
            panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 150));
            JButton okBut = new JButton("OK");
            panel.add(okBut);
            background.add(panel);

            okBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dispose();
                    parent.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

            Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    panel.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();

            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            setUndecorated(true);
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        private ImageIcon createImage() {
            ImageIcon icon = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/black/stackoverflow-2-256.png");
                icon = new ImageIcon(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SplashDialogDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return icon;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SplashDialogDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                new SplashDialogDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```